# What is Pulse Wave Velocity, any benefit in measuring it?

Tags: heart

Some health products (e.g. smart scales) boast that they measure the heart's Pulse Wave Velocity. Is there any benefit in monitoring this parameter and trying to "improve" it via training/eating?

Comment: Related: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/18795